# How do I build a non-biomorphic AI?

Tags: gurps-4e

I'm building an ally for one of my players in a GURPS game, but I'm having trouble figuring out the point cost of a non-biomorphic AI.  Basically, this AI lives in a computer that the player wears on him, and doesn't have the ability to operate a robot.  I can find the rules for making a biomorphic robot AI, but I can't find any kind of lense or meta-trait that describes an AI that lives in a sessile computer.

Is there an extant lense or meta-trait that is appropriate for an AI that lives in a computer, and not a robot?  If not, how would you build such a lense?

I figure that this would include No Fine Manipulators(No Manipulators) and No Legs(Sessile), as well as the Machine and AI meta-traits, but I'm mostly interested in whether this would be sufficient, or if there are things that I'm missing.

Comment: Tangentially, this is one of the classic "problem ally" types: [the hidden familiar](http://www.mygurps.com/a_allies.html?p=a&v=0). Consider reading that to help dodge the traps a sentient gadget lays for GMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out this question was already answered in one of the GURPS books, specifically Transhuman Space - Changing Times.  In that book there are rules for creating characters who are artificial intelligences inside various robot bodies (or "cybershells"), one of which is the Microframe cybershell, which is basically a modern computer.  The full template is:

> Attribute Modifiers: ST-10 [-100]; HT+2 [20].
>
> Secondary Characteristic
> Modifiers: HP+8 [16]; SM -3.
>
> Advantages: Damage Resistance 5 (Can’t
> Wear Armor, -40%) [15]; Doesn’t Breathe [20]; Machine [25];
> Telecommunication (Cable Jack; Sensie, +80%) [9]; Telecommunication
> (Infrared Communication) [10]; Telecommunication (Radio; Sensie, +80%)
> [18]. Perks: Accessory (Computer) [1].
>
> Disadvantages: Cybershell Body
> [-15]; Increased Consumption 4 (1/2 hour endurance if detached from
> power) [-40]; No Legs (Sessile) [-50]; No Manipulators [-50]; No Sense
> of Smell/Taste [-5]; Restricted Diet (Very Common, electrical power
> supply) [-10].

The only real difference between the sizes of machine are their HP and SM, so presumably a smaller "nanoshell" machine could be made as a wearable computer.  There is another cybershell for wearable computers, but the traits for that one make it sound like it's supposed to be a helmet with enhanced vision, which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just start with the standard disadvantages? In 4e, I would start with p.145 in the Characters book, where both ***No Fine Manipulators*** and ***No Legs*** disadvantages are described.

Perhaps the *Sessile* version of ***No Legs*** could be reduced to represent the ease of mobility for a wearable AI?

Or maybe just hit the Meta-Traits section on p.263 and see what you can find to springboard off of with the ***Machine***, ***Mentality (AI)***, and ***Morphology*** Meta Traits?

***EDIT:*** Perhaps you might check Ultra-Tech in the *Machines as Characters* section? pp.27-28 have selection of Machine Intelligence Lenses that might get you closer to your goal.

Is the AI it's own creature? Then try ***Volitional AI***, for example.

I'm not sure what you think you are missing, or what aspects of the ally character you think you might not be representing correctly. Maybe you could add more details to the question?

Comment: That's sort of the direction that I was thinking, but I feel like No Fine Manipulators(No Manipulators) and No Legs(Sessile) don't quite cover it. It certainly would include Machine and AI, but I feel like there are further disadvantages that may or may not apply, and my GURPS-fu isn't strong enough to suss out what works and what doesn't.   I'd add a little more clarification to the question, I guess.